# Admob ads failed to load ad 3

Tags: java, android, admob

I have been trying to solve this problem but this is not working please help me out in this problem... ads were showing perfectly in my application but now they are not loading and returning error 3 on AdFailedToEvent event... searched google but i found the solution of mediation group i added that but that did not help me out
Here is picture of my mediation group below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTf1Z.png

Comment: Have you solved the issue? @salman

Comment: @SudheeshMohan Yes brother i solved it...this was a problem of google ads fill rate.. Google does not give you much ads at very first time...this is a whole procedure which works gradually

Comment: Ads works fine in the old version of my app in playstore. But now when I updated gradle and firebase version I am getting error code 3. But test ads works fine

Comment: @SudheeshMohan same error i am also getting now... it was working fine till 7th of november

Comment: but when updated it it is showing error code 3

Comment: Hi guys, did you solve this issue? 
I've the same problem: ads work on published playstore app version, now I updated components in my app and admob returns "failed to load: 3". 
But with test banners works...How did you solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a debug build on your device, the chances of real ads being shown is very limited.
Switch to a release build and real ads will start to show.

I have experienced this many times but after searching Internet for days, I figured it out on my own.